# Regarding database backup during up gradation of website

Tags: php, database, postgresql, drupal-7

We are developing one website and creating some tables as part our customised module development.I have observed many tables get created as part of our drupal installation.  Now I wanted to replace the newly developed website(drupal 7) with the old website(drupal 7).

I wanted to take the backup of old site then I will replace the new website. I have taken database  backup of customized module and "user" & "user_roles" from default tables.

Could you please suggest me what are other default tables needs to be taken backup before replacing the new website ?

Note : I am using Postgresql .

Regards,

Santosh Kumar Dash

Comment: BACK IT ALL UP! Database and Code and EVERYTHING. If you need to put it back in a hurry thats the safest way

Comment: You can always restore it in pieces, but it is imperative that you have ALL the pieces to work with in the backup

Comment: It's best to backup whole DB. Clear the cache before backup to reduce backup size. Also try out "Backup and Migrate" module - it allows doing backup and restore from back-end. Also scheduled backups and more.